# Continuity of $f(x)=x^4$ at $x=2$ by definition

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

I would like some feedback on my attempt of proving that $f(x)=x^4$ is continuous at $x=2$.

**My approach:** Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. We need to find $\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that whenever $|x-2|<\delta$ then $|x^4-16|<\epsilon$. As $$|x^4-16|=|(x^2-4)(x^2+4)|=|x-2||x+2||x^2+4|$$ we have these undesired $|x+2|$, $|x^2+4|$ factors that we need to bound. Let $\delta<1$. Then $x-2\in (-1,1)$, and so $x\in(1,3)$. Consequently, $|x+2|<5$ and

$$-1<x-2<1 \Leftrightarrow 0 < x^2-4x+4 < 1 \Leftrightarrow 4<4x<x^2+4<1+4x<13$$

and hence $|x^2+4|<13$. As $13\times 5=65$, simply take $\delta=\min\left\{1,\dfrac{\epsilon}{65}\right\}$.

Does this look fine? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks OK to me. +1 for the explicit note that

> we have these undesired factors that we need to bound

telling the reader just what you are thinking.

For $x$ between $1$ and $3$   your bound $|x^2+4| < 13 $ is more straightforward than your argument.

Comment: Ethan, just as one old hand to another, I ask: isn’t it the case that an increasing function from one interval to another, if surjective, must be continuous? This gives you all the powers, and I suppose a number of other useful functions. If I were still teaching, I would subject my students to this once, just to see what happened.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, though I hadn't noted that. It's a long time since I taught any analysis (and I'm recently retired now). In this case the OP wants a proof from first principles.

Comment: Righto. I wasn’t recommending this to OP, but noting it, ’cause it occurred to me only relatively recently too. (I retired as of 01/01/00)